# Why does this code hang with multiprocessing but work with multiprocess?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am experiencing issues with `multiprocessing.Pool` function. Looking around I saw that there is another "version" called `multiprocess.Pool` and eventually with this library the code worked.

My code before (the task was running forever) :

```
with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=10, maxtasksperchild=5000) as pool:
            job_iter = pool.imap_unordered(
                call_runner,
                [(row, i, date_total) for i, row in df.iterrows()],
                chunksize=100,
            )
```

My code after (working):

```
with multiprocess.Pool(processes=10, maxtasksperchild=5000) as pool:
            job_iter = pool.imap_unordered(
                call_runner,
                [(row, i, date_total) for i, row in df.iterrows()],
                chunksize=100,
            )
```

Do you know which are the relevant differences between the two libraries? Thanks!!

Comment: "What are the differences?" in general is too broad to be on-topic. "What specific difference caused the one to work when the other did not?", OTOH, is probably within our scope.

Comment: multiprocess is an extension of the builtin multiprocessing library: https://pypi.org/project/multiprocess/

Comment: ...it would be very helpful to provide a [mre] -- extending your question to the shortest possible code that lets someone else produce the hang on their own system.

Comment: (As an aside -- early in Stack Overflow's history we had a plague of people advertising their projects/libraries by asking questions for which their -- often commercial/expensive -- tool was the answer, until we changed the rules to make that very thoroughly disallowed; so this question smells a little suspicious to someone who's been around that long).